# How to set dtypes when converting a dataframe to a numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy structured array that looks like this:

```
>>> arr
array([(b'00:59:59.785634', 60.87), (b'01:00:00.187634', 60.88),
    (b'01:00:00.188634', 60.88), ...,
    (b'23:59:58.668559', 60.93), (b'23:59:58.668559', 60.92),
    (b'23:59:58.668559', 60.93)],
    dtype=[('Date', 'S15'), ('Value', '<f4')])
```

When I convert it to a pandas dataframe, The values of Value column change their form.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( arr )
                    Date      Value  
0       b'00:59:59.785634'  60.869999     
1       b'01:00:00.187634'  60.880001    
2       b'01:00:00.188634'  60.880001     
3       b'01:00:00.189634'  60.860001    
4       b'01:00:00.190634'  60.860001  

>>> df.Value
Name: Value, Length: 176195, dtype: float32
```

It's still OK, because it prints out the same value as the array.

```
>>> str( df['Value'][0] )
'60.87'
```

But a problem occurs when I have done modifying the dataframe and try to convert the dataframe to an array again.

```
>>> new_arr = df.values
array([[b'00:59:59.785634', 60.869998931884766],
    [b'01:00:00.187634', 60.880001068115234],
    [b'01:00:00.188634', 60.880001068115234],
    ...,
    [b'23:59:58.668559', 60.93000030517578],
    [b'23:59:58.668559', 60.91999816894531],
    [b'23:59:58.668559', 60.93000030517578]], dtype=object)

>>> str( new_arr[0][1] )
'60.869998931884766'        # != '60.87'
```

I think the original dtype(float32) is lost during the last conversion. How can I still get `'60.87'` even after converting the dataframe to an array with `.values` attribute?

My question is why it prints out different results('60.87' and '60.869998931884766') and how to keep the type. I think if the values can be the same when converting an array to a dataframe, there should be some ways to preserve the values when converting them **the other way around**.

Comment: Floats are not stored as base-10 decimals. Therefore, a print representation may not match internal representation.

Comment: When I try this `df.dtypes` shows an `object` Date column and `float32` Value column.  `df.values` is object dtype array.  The elements are base Python strings and floats.  Display of Python scalars is different from display for arrays.  Compare `df.values[:,1]` with `df.values[:,1].astype('float32')`

Comment: Also look at `df['Value'].values`.